# Exception "input string was not in correct format" when adding field to list view

Tags: winforms, datetime

i am trying to add a field in list box **"Winforms"** And it does add as it supposed to but with an error saying the **input string was not in correct format** and i just can't figure out why Here is my Code Below

```
try
        {
            int days = int.Parse(txtExpiry.Text);
            DateTime added = DateTime.Now.AddDays(days);
            string expdate = added.ToString("d", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-NZ"));
            //DateTime.Parse(expdate) = shwdate.ToString(");
            shwdate.Text = expdate;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            RadMessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the error comes from this line: `int.Parse(txtExpiry.Text);` The text in the textbox cannot be converted to an integer.

If you're using a textbox for integer values - I would recommend using a "numeric up-down", instead of a regular textbox.

Also I would **strongly** recommend changing the **catch** block as follows:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //show "ToString()" to see the full call-stack, makes debugging a lot easier
    RadMessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks You for the Valuable Suggestion. Used the Spin Editor